# random.sample() how to control reproducibility

Tags: python, random, random-seed

Is there a way to control random.sample()? I fix seed that standard way:

```
def seed_everything(seed=42):
    random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
 
seed_everything(42)
```

Nevertheless the result of code below is different every time:

```
idxT=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
idxT = [
        idxT[j] for j in sorted(random.sample(range(len(idxT)), 3))
    ]
idxT
```

Comment: Are you calling `seed_everything` before “every time”? Also, in this case, I’d recommend creating your own `random` object, `rng = random.Random(42)`, and calling `rng.sample`.

Comment: @Ry- I run def seed_everything() once at the beginning of jupyter notebook. "every time" I mean that code gives different sampling at every run of cell with sampling (seed_everything() not in that cell). Thanks for answering! Do I need calling rng.sample in this case?

Answer (score 5):

I think Ry is on the right track: if you want the return value of `random.sample()` to be the same every time it is called you will have to call `random.seed()` with the same value prior to every invocation of `random.sample()`.

Here are three simplified examples to illustrate:

```
random.seed(42)
idxT = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(3):
        print(random.sample(idxT, 3))
    print()
```

Output:

```
[5, 0, 6]
[5, 2, 1]
[1, 6, 0]

[5, 6, 4]
[0, 4, 3]
[0, 6, 5]
```

```
idxT = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for _ in range(2):
    random.seed(42)
    for _ in range(3):
        print(random.sample(idxT, 3))
    print()
```

Output:

```
[5, 0, 6]
[5, 2, 1]
[1, 6, 0]

[5, 0, 6]
[5, 2, 1]
[1, 6, 0]
```

```
idxT = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for _ in range(2):
    for _ in range(3):
        random.seed(42)
        print(random.sample(idxT, 3))
    print()
```

Output:

```
[5, 0, 6]
[5, 0, 6]
[5, 0, 6]

[5, 0, 6]
[5, 0, 6]
[5, 0, 6]
```